# C++11 seed_seq initialization

Tags: c++, random, c++11

The header file `<random>` allows for the seed sequence's internal sequence to be initialized. An object of class `seed_seq` can be constructed in multiple ways. I am curious about one of the ways, specifically what C++ technique is being used.

I am looking at the website here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/random/seed_seq/seed_seq/

And in the example section, I see this line:

```
std::seed_seq seed2 = {102,406,7892};
```

What exactly is happening here? It appears a class object is being assigned to an array. I have looked at the initializer-list construct, copy assignment constructor, and I am still confused on what exactly is happening.

I understand `std::seed_seq seed3 (foo.begin(),foo.end());` and `std::seed_seq seed1;`. The first code snippet (`seed3`) is calling the `seed_seq` constructor with arguments `foo.begin()` and `foo.end()`, and the second code snippet (`seed1`) is being constructed using the default constructor.

Comment: Just a side-note: cplusplus.com is a bad website. Use http://cppreference.com.

Comment: This is construction-by-initializer-list, no?  I'd expect this is calling `seed_seq<int>(initializer_list<int>)`.

Comment: There was an example on cppreference.com also. It is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq/seed_seq, and I am looking at the 8-th line of the example.

Comment: @jrand: Also you can read about list initialization in C++ Standard, 8.5.4 (N3337)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I entirely understood your question, as you have almost given the answer yourself. Using something like `{102,406,7892}` is a initializer list. A constructor method (or actually any method) with a signature like `MyClass::MyClass(std::initializer_list<int> args)` can take this.

You may iterate over it using the normal iterator methods `begin()` and `end()`. Its basicly just a convenient way to pass a list of arbitary length **in code** without having to instancinate a "normal" `std::list` or `std::vector` (and keep calling `push_back()` on that) or an array.

As a bonus, you can also construct the standard containers using initializer lists: `std::vector<std::string> vec {"hello", "world"}`. This allows you to use the standard containers as argument types for functions that can still be called using an initializer_list.

Comment: Construction with a braced-initializer-list doesn't have to invoke an `initializer_list` constructor, although it will be preferred if available.

Comment: Thank you. From the comments and this website: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization , it appears a constructor method with an initializer list only or an initializer list as the first argument, can be called using class_name class_object = {arg1, arg2, ... } (10th example of syntax in the website)

Comment: Ah yes, you could of course also have a standard container as parameter, as those can also be constructed from initializer_lists (as I have stated xD).